# Junit how to import file properties to service in test

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, junit, backend

I am writting unit test and have some values from application.yaml property file. In my test before i can go into service method values are imported from test/resources, but when go into service im getting null value properties here is some code :
test :

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.yaml")
public class AmadeusClientUnitTest {

    @Value("${clientId}")
    public String clientId;

    @Value("${clientSecret}")
    public String clientSecret;

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    private AmadeusClient amadeusClient;

    @Test
    void shouldGetAmadeusObj() {
        amadeusClient.getAmadeusObj();

        verify(Amadeus.builder(any(), any()).build());
    }
```

application-test.yaml :

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: test
clientId: "clientId"
clientSecret: "secret"
```

and here is service :

```
@Service
public class AmadeusClient {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AmadeusClient.class.getName());

    @Value("${clientId}")
    private String clientId;
    @Value("${clientSecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    public Amadeus getAmadeusObj() {
        return Amadeus.builder(clientId, clientSecret).setLogger(LOGGER).build();
    }
}
```

[image: debug]

[image: debug]

I put some imgs from debugging test. Am I missing any properties ?
Thanks for any help i feel like i am missing "dot" somewhere. Appreciate for any tip here. Have a nice day

Comment: As a rule of thumb nothing in Spring can be `null` when using `@Autowired` or `@Value`. If that happens, spring will error out resulting in an message that something couldn't be resolved. The fact that that doesn't happens means you aren't using Spring for this. Looking at your test that is the case as you are using `@Spy` and `@InjectMocks`. So you aren't using a Spring managed instance, use `@Autowired` instead of `@Spy`. Also the `@TestPropertySource` isn't needed that is already covered by the `@ActiveProfile` and regular loading of properties.

Comment: it worked, thanks. I found something to learn